# Configuring jetty's Stdout/Stderr to redirect to log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, jetty, slf4j

I tried to configure jetty with log4j. I could create some logfiles. However, I would like to capture/configure all output with log4j even stdout and stderr.

Is there a way to configure the jetty-logging.xml so that it uses slf4j and redirects stdout and stderr to some defined Logger, I can then configure in my log4j.properties?

I am thinking of something like this:

```
<Configure id="logging" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog">
   <!-- redirect stdout and stderr to logger with name 'StdoutStderrLogger' -->
    <New id="ServerLog" class="???">
      <Arg>
        <New class="???">
           <!-- ?????  -->
          <Get id="ServerLogName" name="???"/>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </New>

    <Get name="rootLogger">
        <Call name="info"><Arg>redirect stdout and stderr to logger with name 'StdoutStderrLogger' <Ref refid="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
    </Get>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>

</Configure>
```

Thanks already for your answers